# How to force file download on Telerik RadEditor?

Tags: c#, telerik, mime, radeditor

I am using Document Manager in Telerik RadEditor.

Once I upload .txt file and click on that link, it opens on the browser instead of downloading it. How to force download that file without going in to .htaccess or other server changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: using RadEditor alone you can't.

In order to make a browser-viewable file type be served as a download you must send it to the client's browser with a 'Content-Disposition' type of 'attachment'. Doing so is fairly simple, however it requires server-side code that would be outside of the scope of RadEditor.

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/path/to/file.txt"));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Displosition", "attachment;filename=file.txt;size=" + bytes.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Unless you want to write a specific handler for serving the file in question, your only option is to instruct users that they must 'Right-Click > Save Link As...' on your text file link.

Comment: solved that issue by changing .htaccess file through asapi. Thanks anyway

Comment: @StewieGriffin May I suggest posting your solution as an answer- for historical purposes? Mine doesn't exactly solve the problem and I'm curious what your .htaccess looks like.